# Identificar se uma matriz é triangular superior, inferior ou diagonal

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, matriz

Preciso receber uma matriz e identificar se ela é uma matriz triangular superior, uma matriz triangular inferior ou uma matriz diagonal (superior+inferior)

Escrevi um código inicialmente para descobrir se é diagonal (já que pra mim seria um pouco mais fácil), mas nem ela está rodando, explorando as variáveis percebo que o contador não está aumentando, ou seja, a função nao esta rodando, mas o programa nao devolve erro em nenhum lugar.

Segue o programa:

```py
n = int(input())

M = []
for a in range(n):
    M.append(input().split(" "))

print(M)

linhas = len(M)
colunas = len(M[0])

cont = 0

for i in range(linhas):
    for j in range(colunas):
        if i != j and M[i][j] == 0:
            cont = cont + 1

if cont == 2*n:
    print("diagonal")
```

Comment: Pra ficar mais legível, tenta fazer um "Ctrl +K" na parte do código pra poder postar aqui.

Comment: Outro detalhe, sua matriz está recebendo uma string, ou seja, quando você checa se M[i][j] == 0, isso vai falhar, pois na verdade M[i][j] é "0". Pra facilitar, só voce fazer o seguinte: M.append([int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]), que ai voce ja recebe os valores como inteiros.

Answer (score 0):

Acho mais fácil assumir que a matriz é superior e inferior e provar o contrário em cada caso.

Para checar se a matriz **não é** inferior basta checar se tem algum elemento em uma coluna de índice maior que o da linha que não seja zero. Faz algo parecido para checar se a matriz não é superior.

```py
print("Digite o número de linhas")
n = int(input())

M = []
for a in range(n):
    print("Digite os elementos na linha {} separados por espaço".format(a))
    M.append([int(x) for x in input().split(" ")])

linhas = len(M)
colunas = len(M[0])


# Vamos assumir inicialmente que a matriz é superior
a_matriz_e_sup = True
# e inferior também
a_matriz_e_inf = True

for i in range(linhas):
    # Só precisamos verificar colunas maiores que 'i' e temos certeza que 'i' e
    # 'j' nunca serão iguais (não precisamos de "i != j" no "if"
    for j in range(i+1, colunas):
        if M[i][j] != 0:
            # Se encontrarmos algum elemento diferente de zero em ao menos uma
            # coluna de índice maior que o índice da linha então a matriz não
            # pode ser inferior
            a_matriz_e_inf = False

for i in range(1, linhas):
    for j in range(0, i):
        if M[i][j] != 0:
            # Semelhante ao caso anterior
            a_matriz_e_sup = False

print("Matriz")
for linha in M:
    print(linha)

if a_matriz_e_sup and a_matriz_e_inf:
    print("diagonal")
else:
    if a_matriz_e_sup:
        print("superior")
    if a_matriz_e_inf:
        print("inferior")
```